# MMC crashes on Server 2008 R2 when checking "Install DNS Server" box?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Okay this is bizarre. I just DCPROMO'd this server at home to set it up with AD. Upon reboot, I tried to get into the DNS server and it says "Access Denied". Okay so let's try that again.

I remove the role, reboot, and go to install the role again. Now, when I check the box to install the DNS server, the MMC thing crashes immediately! Here's the error I'm getting..

> Description:
>    Stopped working
>
> Problem signature:
>    Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3
>    Problem Signature 01:    mmc.exe
>    Problem Signature 02:    6.1.7600.16385
>    Problem Signature 03:    4a5bc808
>    Problem Signature 04:    mscorlib
>    Problem Signature 05:    2.0.0.0
>    Problem Signature 06:    4d4cbca7
>    Problem Signature 07:    4212
>    Problem Signature 08:    a9
>    Problem Signature 09:    System.NullReferenceException
>    OS Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.272.7
>    Locale ID:   1033
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
>    C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would try installing SP1 for Windows Server 2008 R2 as it does not appear to be installed. If the process still crashes you can troubleshoot the cause then.

I would also try installing the role through dism. Some server core specific examples are at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441260(WS.10).aspx. But you can adopt it for full installations. Just got to get the name right. Use /get-features to get the name and then install it.